# Sorting output of integers with commas in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program to find prime numbers between user inputted n1 and n2. The output should just be the primes numbers with commas separating them. For example:

n1 = 1,
n2 = 10,
output: 3,5,7

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primes {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1, n2, flag = 0, i, j;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n1 = sc.nextInt();
    n2 = sc.nextInt();
    for (i = n1; i <= n2; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
                flag = 1;
            }

        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            System.out.printf("%d,", i);
        }
   }
 }
}
```

But my output is: `3,5,7,` with that extra comma. How do I fix that?

Comment: print `","` only as soon as the second number to print. And you have to print first the  `","` , then print the number, not the reverse as you do actually.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
System.out.printf("%d,", i);
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%d", i);
```

for the first prime you're printing out, and use

```
System.out.printf(",%d", i);
```

for subsequent primes.

Also, be aware that the primes between 1 and 10 are 2,3,5,7 not 3,5,7.